stream.on('exit') in gulp-nodemon
I'm a newbie to gulp. So this question might be obvious.
var gulp = require('gulp');
var shell = require('gulp-shell');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/gulp').forEach(function(task) {
    require('./gulp/' + task);
});

// Define tasks to start and stop MongoDB and Redis
gulp.task('start-mongodb', shell.task([
  'sudo systemctl start mongod'
]));

gulp.task('start-redis', shell.task([
  'sudo systemctl start redis-server'
]));

gulp.task('stop-mongodb', shell.task([
    'sudo systemctl stop mongod'
]));

gulp.task('stop-redis', shell.task([
    'sudo systemctl stop redis-server'
]));

gulp.task('start-services', gulp.series('start-mongodb', 'start-redis'));
gulp.task('stop-services', gulp.series('stop-mongodb', 'stop-redis'));

gulp.task('build', gulp.parallel('css', 'js'));

gulp.task('dev:server', function(done) {
    // Create nodemon instance and save it
    var stream = nodemon({ script: 'server.js'
      , ext: 'js'
      , ignore: ['ng*', 'gulp*', 'assets*']})
    
    stream.on('exit', function() {
      console.log('Stopping services and server...');
      gulp.series('stop-services', function() {
        console.log('Services stopped. Exiting...');
        process.exit(0);
      });
    })
});

gulp.task('dev', gulp.series('start-services', gulp.parallel('watch:css', 'watch:js', 'dev:server')));

the above is my gulpfile.js.
Everything works in the task dev until i hit ctrl+c, I was expecting for the following:
-> Console logging 'Stopping services and server...'
-> runs stop-mongodb
-> runs stop-redis
-> Console logging 'Services stopped. Exiting...'
-> And then, finally the process exiting.
But this happened:
-> Stopping services and server...
-> [12:43:25] The following tasks did not complete: dev, <parallel>, dev:server
-> Did you forget to signal async completion?
It clearly didn't stop redis neither mongodb.
I searched for solutions everywhere, there were no clear documentations on this on the internet.
I hope someone response soon.

I'm not terribly familiar with gulp, do you need to await the gulp.series call?

@Joe where? in dev? or in stop-services? or everywhere? i assume there is a callback that can be used instead?

gulp.series returns a composed task, which is an asynchronous function.  I suspect you would need to either await that function or explicitly call it, but I don't have gulp installed anywhere to test that.
